# Upgrade App Service Plan operating system

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We are busy migrating our application from a classic Cloud Service to a new App Service model.
We've done this before, but are now stumbling to something strange and I'm suspecting it might have something to do with the underlying operating system.

The Cloud Service is running on a VM with the Windows Server 2016 family installed (OS Version: 10.0.14393 according to this link: https://www.gaijin.at/en/lstwinver.php)

From what I can tell, the App Service Plan has a much older operating system installed, because Kudu is giving me the following OS information

> OS version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

Which apparently is Windows Server 2012.

In order to test my hypothesis I want to upgrade the OS version of the App Service Plan, but I can't figure out how to do this or even if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently, web app is hosted on Windows Server 2012.

> In order to test my hypothesis I want to upgrade the OS version of the
>   App Service Plan, but I can't figure out how to do this or even if
>   this is possible.

Currently, it is not possible. Now Azure Web app is not supported on Windows Server 2016. Based on my experience, it will supported in the future.

Comment: Currently, if you want to host your app on Server 2016, maybe you could select Azure VM.

Comment: Thanks, I expected as much. A VM is possible, but we'd like to move to an even lighter PaaS solution, compared to the Cloud Service we have now. Using a VM would only set us back a step. I'll just do some proof-of-concepts to check if the issue really has to do something with the underlying operating system.